# How to secure an endpoint

Tags: express, security, mern

I have an endpoint written in expressjs

```
router.post("/mkBet", async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body)
const betToPush = new Bet({
    addr: req.body.address,
    betAmount: req.body.amount,
    outcome: req.body.didWin,
    timePlaced: Math.round(+new Date()/1000)
})

try {
    const newBet = await betToPush.save()
    res.status(201).json(newBet)
} catch(err) {
    
    res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
}})
```

And I am trying to make it so that it can only be called when an action is performed on the frontend. So users cannot call it with custom arguments to make it so the outcome is always true. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to securely tell what client sent the request. In other words, a request from your client and a different one can be identical in general.

Talking about unmodified browsers (as opposed to non-browser tools like Postman), you can tell the origin of the request (~the url loaded in the browser when the request was sent) with some confidence from the Origin and Referer request headers. However, your backend needs authentication and authorization anyway.

With the latter two in place, ie. with proper security implemented on the server-side, it doesn't matter anymore what client sends the requests.